# How can I specify Ehcache settings with Play 1.2.4

Tags: playframework, ehcache, playframework-1.x

Is it possible to set Ehcache properties from the application.conf with Play framework?

i.e. in application.conf can I specify something like:

```
timeToLiveSeconds=36000
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As far as I know, this is not supported. Configuration options supported by Play 1.2.4 are documented [here](http://www.playframework.org/documentation/1.2.4/configuration) and there is nothing like that on the list. Ehcache-specific options can't be found from the Cache API of Play either, as it is supposed to provide a generic interface to cache functionality, independent of the actual implementation (Ehcache, Memcached).

Comment: It doesn't feel right as it is possible to specify memcached properties! I am trying to specify a maximum TTL value for all cached objects, which is possible for memcached. Why not ehcache?

Answer (score 2):

Gist at https://gist.github.com/oscarrenalias/5063249 suggests placing ehcache.xml to conf/ folder but I don't know whether this works for Play 1.